# Multi-lingual Laravel Site

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.1, multilingual

## I have

a laravel site, and everything is in English.

---

## I need

to change the entire site to Chinese friendly.

---

## I try

On top of my master view, I update `<html lang="en">` to `<html lang="zh">`
Site, seemed to be the same.

---

## I know

that we can leverage Laravel [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization) and load the proper texts base on the region of the visitor. But if I chose to do it that way, meaning that I will have to create those files manually - I want to save this to my last resort, when I couldn't change the language automatically.

---

What should I start look into ?

How would one implement this kind of feature in there existing app ?

I'm opening to any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use localization feature. If want to have Chinese version only, you should create new lang files and change locale without changing routes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

Also, you can save some time and download [translated validation, auth lang files](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang/tree/master/src/zh-CN) etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start looking into them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an alternative, don't use the Laravel localization package, instead use this one: https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext -- the files it uses (.po files) are more industry standard.  There are dedicated .po file editors that translators and translation companies commonly use to provide the translation data.